# Create a class based on a string and pass the constructor arguments at the same time

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that basically creates an instance of a *class* on-the-fly:

```
$class = 'user';
return new $class;
```

The challenge is that I have the constructor's arguments in an *array* format and they're obviously different from class to class -- so there is no pattern at all that I can make anything on top of that. There are some workarounds here to extract these arguments from the array and pass it all through in a way like this:

```
$args = array( 'one', 'two' );
// some code to generate $arg1, $arg2, etc.
return new $class( $arg1, $arg2 );
```

However, I really prefer to do it in a smarter way. As far as I can see there is no way to make use of [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) unless I forget about the *constructor* and initialize it after instantiation.

**Update**

Basically I'm looking for something like this:

```
return magic_func( 'className', array('one', 'two') );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return (new ReflectionClass($class))->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php

Comment: Thanks! for some reason I got a syntax error `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`, however when I did break it down into two statements -- like in the manual, then it worked out as expected!